# Jeypore Reserve Forest in Assam, India Shapefile

Tags: data-request, india, geospatial

Does anybody have the shapefile for Jeypore reserve forest which is adjacent to [Dehing patkai wildlife sanctuary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dehing_Patkai_Wildlife_Sanctuary), Assam, India?

Answer (score 1):

[Bhuvan (Indian Geo-Platform of ISRO)](http://bhuvan.nrsc.gov.in/bhuvan_links.php) looks like a good place to find this data, although to be clear, I could not find it.
[Assum](http://bhuvan.nrsc.gov.in/state/AS) has it's own geo portal linked to in Bhuvan, though the search results were lacking, and not clear in that they were results or an error.
There's other portals that may be fruitful linked there too, including Forestry, Agriculture, Environment & Forest, ENVIS, CRIS, etc.
[ENVIS - Environmental Information System](http://bhuvan.nrsc.gov.in/governance/moefcc_envis) has Forest And Ecology layers, including one for National Parks; however, using it produces the same results: I can't tell if there is no data, or if the service is erroring out.
Lastly, [there is a create your own shapefile](http://bhuvan-cas.nrsc.gov.in/cas/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Fbhuvan-mapper.nrsc.gov.in%2Fonlineshp%2Flogin%3Freferer%3D%252Fonlineshp%252F) option, however it requires a sign up so I didn't get past the wall to explore more.
tl;dr; - this data looks like it should live here, however it is not clear to me because it seems like the UI is hard to understand.